# React Native getInitialURL() is not called in Android

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I did the all installations required to use deep linking. I can launch app from the external URL which I placyed to my website and its working fine. I can listen upcoming URLs if my app is already launched but only problem I cant get initial URL if my app was just launched from the URL.

Linking.getInitialURL() never called, I dont know whats the problem..

My Code

```
componentDidMount(){
        Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
           console.warn('called');
            if (url) {
              console.warn('Initial url is: ' + url);
            }
        }).catch(err => console.warn('An error occurred', err));
}
```

My Android XML

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="xxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
      >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data android:scheme="spark" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
       <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
```

My package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^0.1.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^0.1.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-billing": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.3.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },
```

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: nope still same.. I actually expect some answer as well..

Answer (score 1):

If the application is already launched, it won't reload the component and so it won't execute your lifecycle methods. Try adding a linking event listener and see

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
},
componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
},
_handleOpenURL(event) {
  console.log(event.url);
}
```